# How to find the amount of solutions of polynomial congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

The given congruence is $ x^4-5x-6 ≡ 0 $ mod $(100^{100})$. Find the amount of it’s solutions.

I’ve factorised it: $ (x+1)(x-2)(x^2+x+3) ≡ 0$ mod $(100^{100})$.

From here I get solutions for the first two brackets: $ x ≡ -1 $ mod $(5^{200}2^{200}) $ and $ x ≡ 2 $ mod $(5^{200}2^{200}) $.

The left one bracket is: $ x^2+x+3 ≡ 0$ mod $(5^{200}2^{200})$.

Using the Chinese remainder theorem: $ \begin{cases}
x^2+x+3 ≡ 0(5^{200})
\\
x^2+x+3 ≡ 0(2^{200})
\end{cases}
$

Using the Legendre’s(Jacobi’s) symbol and the following facts:

1. if we have $ax+by+c ≡ 0$ mod(m) and $a,b,c$ are integers, m – a positive integer and $GCD(2a,m)=1$, than the given expression and $y^2 ≡ b^2-4ac$ mod(m) have the same amount of solutions.
2. if $p$ is prime and do not divide $a$, then $x^2 ≡ a$ mod $p^n$ is solvable(and has two solutions), if a is quadratic residue modulo p.

With given information, I get that the first expression in my system has 2 solutions. What about the second one? What should I do with 2 exponent?

The answer in my textbook for the amount of solutions for the firstly given expression is 8.

Comment: 1) Note that $x^2 + x + 3$ is always odd, so has no solutions $\pmod{2^{200}}$. 2) Using your fact 2, show that $x^2 + x + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^{200}}$ has 2 solutions. 3) Conclude that the number of solutions is $2 \times 4=8 $ by CRT. 4) Note that your fact 2 can be strengthened to "2 solutions if QR, 0 solutions if NQR".

Comment: How about an $x$ that satisfies both $x\equiv -1 \bmod 5^{200}$ and $x\equiv 2 \bmod 2^{200}$ (which exists by CRT)? Or an $x$ that satisfies $x\equiv -1 \bmod 2^{200}$ and $x\equiv 2 \bmod 5^{200}$ ?

Comment: But if the second expression has no solutions, how can I use the fact, that the first expression($ x^2 + x + 3 ≡ 0$ (mod $5^{200}$ has 2 solutions? Doesn’t it mean, that my system has no solutions?

Comment: @Dodomol Elaborating on 3), show that $x^4 - 4x-6 = 0 \pmod{2^{200}}$ has 2 solutions by 1) and $x^4 - 4x-6 = 0 \pmod{5^{200}}$ has 4 solutions by 2). Hence, $x^4 - 4x-6 = 0 \pmod{10^{200}}$  has $ 2 \times 4$ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Show the following

1. $x^2 + x + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{200}}$ has 0 solutions.
2. $ x^4 - 4x -6 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{200}}$ has 2 solutions $\pmod{2^{200}}$.
3. $x^2 + x + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^{200}}$ has 2 solutions $\pmod{5^{200}}$. (There is no need to determine these solutions.)
4. $ x^4 - 4x -6 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^{200}}$ has 4 solutions $\pmod{5^{200}}$.
5. $ x^4 - 4x -6 \equiv 0 \pmod{10^{200}}$ has $2\times 4 = 8 $ solutions $\pmod{10^{200}}$.

Comment: -1 Pulling the solutions out of a hat is magic - not mathematics,. Further, this does not answer any of the OP's questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque 1) This is in addition to the comments that I made, which OP seemed to understand. I'm fleshing out details to correct OP's oversight. 2) Which of OP's questions did I not answer?  3) Not quite sure why you mentioned "pulling the solutions out of a hat is magic", esp since I said there's no need to determine those solutions.